# How to add Vue.config.devtools using Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, devtools

Devtools are not working (Chrome) so my last resource to enable them is to add this:

```
Vue.config.devtools = true
```

In my `main.ts`:

but I'm getting this error:

> Property `config` does not exist on type `typeof import("/node_modules/vue/dist/vue")`.

What could I do?

Comment: can you show the project config, imports or anything else? I simple created a index.ts, npm install vue and I successfully changed Vue.config.devtools to true without getting any errors

Comment: There is a topic on it on github: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/1244